# How to create an array in which the type is abstract but the objects will be derived classes (C++)

Tags: c++

my issue is that i need to be able to create an array of 100 objects. However the objects could be one of four different objects all of which are ultimately derived from an abstract class. I could use 4 separate arrays but it appears as if my teacher only wants us to use one array.

Class structure is : DVD & VHS are derived from Video, CD & Cassette are derived from Audio, Audio & Video are derived from Media. Audio, Video, and Media are all abstract.

Comment: You want `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>`, available from `<vector>` and `<memory>`.

Comment: @KerrekSB Obviously your comment is the correct answer but from experience I fear that these concepts are not to be used in OP’s class. :-\

Comment: you are correct, i am not allowed to use anything from stl

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use pointers.  You can't copy or assign derived types, at least not through a declaration of the base type.

Comment: okay, now my issue is that VS 2010 is saying that the array isn't initialized. `Media *database[100];` is what i am trying to achieve

Comment: How about `Media* database[100] = {};`?  But it may not be an issue: you probably need to populate the array before use, and so the fact that it isn't initialized isn't a problem.  (But do consider using `boost::ptr_vector`, or at least wrapping the array in a class of your own which provides similar functionality.)

Answer (score 0):

for an array
 - the size of type must be known (for reserving the contigous memory)
 - the type may not be an abstract class (for initializing the class must be instantiable)

the only solution for an array is to use pointer indirection, as the size of a pointer is known. you can use raw or smart pointers to base class. when using raw pointers you have to take care of the object destruction before deleting the array. when your array itself resides on the heap do not forget `delete []`.

to overcome these issues a standard [container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++_Standard_Library) like vector should be used with a [smart pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer#C.2B.2B_smart_pointers). only then a simple deletion of the container deletes all the media objects. if the container shall reside on the heap you should as well use a smart pointer to hold it.

make yourself familiar with these two concepts. and if you have no idea what types are best use vector and shared_ptr until you know better.

forgot to say: vector you find in the standard library, shared_ptr you find ther only in a C++11 compiler. if you have an older compiler you have to include [boost libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm).

Comment: cant use vector, my professor only will allow a static array.